# Formating a sum reduce function in Python

Tags: python, sum, format, reduce

I'm trying to format the result of a sum function using reduce. So the input sum_equation([1,5,7]) should return "1 + 5 + 7 = 13".

Here is what I implemented:

```
from functools import reduce


def sum_equation(L):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, L, 0)


def main():
    result = sum_equation([1, 5, 7])
    print("{} + {} = {}".format(x, y, result))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It has an error: NameError: name 'x' is not defined. Can you explain what was incorrect and how I can fix this

Comment: `x` and `y` is only accessible inside the lambda function. Not out side.

Comment: Because ``x`` is not on the scope.

Answer (score 1):

As the original commenters said, the values of `x` and `y` are only accessible within the scope of the lambda expression. Though in this case you can access these values by iterating through `L`.

Edit your `main()` function to the following:

```py
def main(L):
    result = sum_equation(L)
    print(L[0], end=" ")  # print first value without prefix '+'
    for value in L[1:]:
        print("+", value, end=" ")

    print("=", result)  
    # 1 + 5 + 7 = 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
from functools import reduce

def sum_equation(L):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, L, 0)

def main(L):
    result = sum_equation(L)
    print("{} + {} + {} = {}".format(L[0], L[1], L[2], result))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main([1,5,7])

# 1 + 5 + 7 = 13
```

What was wrong is that `x` and `y` where not accessible in `main`. There are several other ways to solve this but I found this way the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

reduce() stores the intermediate result and only returns the final summation value. Whereas, accumulate() returns a iterator containing the intermediate results. The last number of the iterator returned is summation value of the list.
Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reduce-in-python/
This means that it does not return values for x&y so you cant use them separately with print

Answer (score 0):

You need to add global keyword for the variable. Do this -

```
from functools import reduce


def sum_equation(L):
    global x
    global y
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, L, 0)


def main():
    global x
    global y
    result = sum_equation([1, 5, 7])
    print("{} + {} = {}".format(x, y, result))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For more info - [Python scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-scope-of-variables/)

Answer (score 0):

For you question, both `x`and `y` are in the scope of reduce function only, thus, they cannot be accessible in main scope.

You can find another short form achieving your goal for reference as follows:

```
from functools import reduce

print(reduce(lambda x,y: x+' + '+y, [str(i) for i in [1,5,7]]) + ' = ' + str(reduce(reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [1,5,7]))))
```